# Cannot find reference 'Counter' in 'collections.py'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to analyse a Python codebase. To practise this, I decided to go for the `matplotlib`.
I want to run some quick commands to help me with this. For this, I need the Python tokenize feature set and I'll count the variables, methods etc. I see a lot by counting them using `Counter` (from collections). Why does it throw this error?
[image]

I can see other methods from collections:
[image]

Can't run either:

```
/Users/hermanvanderveer/.virtualenvs/advent-of-code-2020/bin/python /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/analyse_code.py
Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
AttributeError: partially initialized module 're' has no attribute 'compile' (most likely due to a circular import)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/analyse_code.py", line 1, in <module>
    from collections import Counter
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py", line 14, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/Users/hermanvanderveer/.virtualenvs/advent-of-code-2020/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 138, in <module>
    from ._version import get_versions
  File "/Users/hermanvanderveer/.virtualenvs/advent-of-code-2020/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/_version.py", line 7, in <module>
    import json
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 106, in <module>
    from .decoder import JSONDecoder, JSONDecodeError
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 3, in <module>
    import re
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/re.py", line 127, in <module>
    import functools
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/functools.py", line 18, in <module>
    from collections import namedtuple
ImportError: cannot import name 'namedtuple' from partially initialized module 'collections' (most likely due to a circular import) (/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py)
```

So why not `Counter`?

Comment: Well the error says `numpy` is not found. You have to install that as well

Comment: So I did and now it got worse. See question.

Comment: could you show us the project directory structure ? I just guess that you can have some local module that can shadow the builtin package

Comment: I could but isn't the error the IDE throws (cannot find reference Counter) a different one than running the code throws (circular import error). It might also be relevant to mention that I'm running code inside the python library; perhaps that is causing trouble?

Comment: You appear to be writing your code inside your matplotlib install directory. Don't do that! It'll cause all sorts of problems, including this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is trying to import `Counter` from `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py` instead of python's standard library.

You can move `analyse_code.py` to a different location and it should work fine.

Comment: Sadly it did not. I'm running it inside the standard library because I aim to analyse it btw